# Conditional expectation of pullback of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T: X \to X$ be a measure preserving invertible transformation and let $F$ be as sub sigma algebra.  My book said it is clear that $E(\chi_{T^{-1}A} | T^{-1}F)(x)=E(\chi_A | F)(Tx)$ but I am not sure why, especially considering how the right hand side doesn't seem to be $T^{-1}F$ measurable.

Edit:  The book doesn't mention it, but I think it is implicitly assuming that $T^{-1}F \subset F$.  This is from an ergodic theory textbook, and this result is used to prove that the conditional entropy satisfies $H(T^{-1}A | T^{-1}F)=H(A|F)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is $F-$ measurable the $Y\circ T$ is $T^{-1}(F)-$ measurable: $$(Y\circ T)^{-1}(E)=T^{-1}(Y^{-1}(E)) \in   T^{-1}(F)$$ since $Y^{-1}(E) \in F$. Take $Y=E(\chi_A|F)$ in this.

Hence, there is no measurabilty problem and no extra assumption is necessary.

Comment: You are taking $E \in T^{-1}F$ right?  How do we know that $Y^{-1}(E) \in F$?

Comment: I guess my misunderstanding is that I think we need to show that preimages of elements of $T^{-1}F$ are in that same sigma algebra.  Is that the definition of measurable with respect to a certain sub algebra?

Comment: $Y$ and $Y\circ T$ are real valued functions. $E$ is a Borel set in the real line. To show that  $Y\circ T$ is $T^{-1}(F)$ measurable we have to show that $(Y\circ T)^{-1}(E)$  is in $T^{-1}(F)$ for very Borel set $E$ in the real line.  @LiterallyanOrange